# Scrollbar on top of tbody content

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar, internet-explorer-7

My problem isn't simple and I can't show the code so I'll try to be precise.

I've got a table generated by a JSP (a tag created by a framework I can't control and specific to my company).

When the scrollbar on the body appear, the content of the "tbody" is moved to the left on every browser to let the place to the scrollbar.
On IE 7, the content doesn't move and the scrollbar is on top of the table.
I can't use width: 97% cause in case the scrollbar doesn't appear the tbody is moved anyway.

If someone got an idea :)
Sorry for the absence of code ...

Comment: Absence of code can be totally corrected by providing a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I don't get what's the difference, i'm not allowed to show any line of code.

Comment: `"I have some code (not shown) that doesn't work, any ideas?"` Really doesn't give us much to go on

Comment: What a shame. Well, in that case, it will be impossible to help you. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycW7E/show/)  but it can't show the problem. In fact, in IE7 mode the scrollbar is always there, so there's nothing that moves or overlaps when the scrollbar becomes active.

Comment: To be more precise, the horizontal scrollbar appears when vertical scrollbar appears because, the vertical scrollbar is over the content ...
I could do an "overflow-x: hidden" but it could hide some content ...
I know it's difficult without code, but anyway thanks :/

Comment: Solution : 
Use a div around the table with a larger width. 
Set table width to 97% so the scrollbar is outside the content. Then the horizontal scrollbar does not appear. 
The scrollbar is outside the table but it's less ugly.

Comment: Someone knows how to put this problem solved ?

Comment: Answer your own question. Mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : 
Use a div around the table with a larger width (so it can contains the scrollbar). 
Set table width to 97% so the scrollbar is outside the content. 
Then the horizontal scrollbar does not appear. 
The scrollbar is outside the table but it's less ugly.